# What if we remove the placeholder text in search as we begin to type in?

Tags: discussion, search

Currently, the placeholder text (`user:id`) in SO search field have to be cleared manually before searching something else.

[image: Searchbar]

What if we clear it as a user starts type-in? Or is it there for a specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That only appears in the search box when you're viewing someone's profile (including yours). It's provided as an easy way to search for posts by that user, rather than having to copy their user ID into the box yourself. If you don't want it to appear in the box, you can go to any other page that isn't a user profile and it won't be there.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the clarification :)